# javascript: compatibility issue from IE to Edge browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I must migrate old asp pages containing javascript code. it seems that Edge can not manage structured data objects like arrays, so that the asp pages working in IE browser, do not in Edge.
Here is a simple example

```
Response.Write "<td><input type=button value=Display onclick=" & chr(34) & "javascript:display(Soc" & i & ")" & chr(34) & "></td>"  ...
```

(html output: "< td>< input type=button value=Display onclick="javascript:display(Soc0)">< /td>")

and display is a very simple javascript function

```
function display(soc){
   alert("DISPLAY");
   alert("soc: " + soc);
   alert("soc name: " + soc.name);
   alert("soc length: " + soc.length);
   for(i=0;i<soc.length;i++)
  {alert("soc(" + i + "): " + soc.item(i).value);}
}
```

running on IE, the javascript output is

soc: [objectHTMLSelectElement]

soc name: Soc0

soc length: 1

soc(0): xx

running on Edge, no result is displayed, and the page goes into error.
of course javascript is enabled and javascript is able to manage simple objects (ie: text or numbers).
is there a way to fix this issue? I would not to review all the asp pages...

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: length on an select object? You want the number of option elements? Code really should not be using ids to reference DOM elements on the page. There should not be `javascript:` in the onclick event, that label is useless.

Comment: `onclick="display('elementId')"` and `function display(id) { const sel = document.querySelector(id); const opts = sel.querySelectorAll('option'); console.log(opts.length); }`

Comment: How do you get the "i" in `Response.Write`? It looks like you can only call `display(Soc)` (instead of `display(Soc0)`) in this way. So, no alert will be displayed. You can provide minimal reproducible code for us.

Comment: thank you all for your suggestions.
I have to specify that 'display' JS function is just a simple test, and the syntax for Soc[i] arrays is right (asp page creates a data table: each row "i" has its corresponding Soc[i] array).
As I said, this JS code was working perfectly in IS browser, while it does not in Edge. No error message is displayed; it seems that the JS code is skipped. 
I wish to find a way (maybe some Edge setting) to get my JS code working, avoiding to rewrite it.

Comment: PS: I also tried the code suggested by epascarello, ie: [html page] onclick="javascript:Display('Soc0')"... and rewrite Display function as suggested. It does not work neither in IE nor in Edge

Comment: for more details, this is the data table code (for each data row "i")

   <input type="text" name="txtSoc<%=i%>" value="Soc. <%=i%>/>

   <select name="Soc<%=i%>">

      <option value="<%=...%>"><%=...%></option>

   </select>

   <input type=button value=Display onclick="javascript:display(Soc<%=i%>,txtSoc<%=i%>)"/>

again, javascript works in IE browser (document.getElementsById(soc) returns the expected values), while Edge browser doesnt react

Answer (score 0):

at last I found a fix. Activating IE mode and registring my site as executable in IE mode, resolved my problem.
thanks all for help